# UITableViewCell with UITextField within the Cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm creating a form similar to "New Contact" from native Contacts app for iOS.

The only way I found is to create a Table View and create a custom Table View Cell.

So far so good...

Now, my TextField only get focus when I click on it, but I want to set the focus to the TextField when I click anywhere of the Table View Cell class I created.

I tried this out:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    [self.txtInputer becomeFirstResponder];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

But it did'nt work as I wish, the focus is set to the last field of the Table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a custom cell with a UITextField as a property in the .h (I've called it textField) of the class. (I've called it TextFieldCell)

Then in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath have the code below. When a cell is tapped you get a reference to the TextFieldCells then from that you can look for the textField property and call becomeFirstResponder on it. Note I have included the enums that you should use for this example. If you do not know what these are place them below your #includes and google into them. Love the enums!!

```
//table view sections
enum
{
    TableViewSectionUsername = 0,
    TableViewSectionPassword,
        TableViewSectionLogin,
    TableViewSectionCount
};

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TextFieldCell *usernameCell = (TextFieldCell*)[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:TableViewSectionUsername]];
    TextFieldCell *passwordCell = (TextFieldCell*)[_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:TableViewSectionPassword]];

    //switch section
    switch(indexPath.section)
    {
        case TableViewSectionUsername:
        {
            [[usernameCell textField] becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        }

        case TableViewSectionPassword:
        {
            [[passwordCell textField] becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        }

        case TableViewSectionLogin:
        {
            if([[[usernameCell textField] text] isEqualToString:@""])
            {
                NSLog(@"Please enter a username");
                [[usernameCell textField] becomeFirstResponder];
                return;
            }

            if([[[passwordCell textField] text] isEqualToString:@""])
            {
                NSLog(@"Please enter a username");
                [[passwordCell textField] becomeFirstResponder];
                return;
            }

            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
        break;
        }
    }

    //deselect table cell
    [_tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

}

Comment: @user2270849 I see you are new to Stack overflow but you need to name your question title to something that better describes your question.